# How to make React Router v6 loader send request only after Auth0?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, auth0

I'm trying to take advantage of React Router loader. Actually it works awesome except for the one case.

I use `Auth0 React SDK` for authorization. I pass `getAccessTokenSilently` to `axios interceptor` so all API calls have Bearer token in header. On some routes I use loader from React Router v6.4 in this way:

**router**

```
              {
                path: PATHS.rawMedia,
                element: <RawMediasPage />,
                loader: rawMediasLoader,
              }
```

It works very nice until I reload a page. On page reload loader sends a request before Auth0. In this case loader sends the request without Bearer token and error is returned from backend.

How to fix that? I was hinted by highly skilled person how to fix that but unfortunatelly I'm not that good. As I understand I need to put `<RouterProvider router={router} />` from `App.tsx` deeper in routing so that Auth0 fires first for token...but I don't understand how to achieve it.

**AuthProvider.tsx**

```
export const AuthProvider = (): JSX.Element | null => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  if (!(domain && clientId)) {
    return null;
  }

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState: any) => {
    navigate(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
      audience={audience}
    >
      <Outlet />
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
```

**ProtectedRoute.tsx**

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { isAuthenticated, isLoading, getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAccessToken = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
        return Promise.resolve(token);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('getAccessToken error:', e);
      }
    };
    httpService(getAccessToken);
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loader areaLoader />;
  }

  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/auth" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
};
```

**router**

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AuthProvider />,
    children: [
      {
        element: <ProtectedRoute />,
        children: [
          {
            element: <InitApp />,
            children: [
              {
                element: <BaseLayout />,
                children: [
                  // many children with loaders
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: PATHS.auth,
        element: <AuthPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: I don't think that putting that provider deeper into the structure will solve the issue completely. It will give Auth0 more time to give you Bearer, but it can happen, that the request will be called sooner, because there is no awaiting taking place.

Answer (score 3):

To overcome your issue, you need to make a few code changes. I will go through them one by one. Please **carefully look** into **file extensions**. Some of them are `.ts` and others are `.tsx`.

**AuthProvider.tsx**

```
export const AuthProvider = = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  if (!(domain && clientId)) {
    return null;
  }

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState: any) => {
    navigate(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
      audience={audience}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
```

**index.tsx**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <Router>
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  </Router>
);
```

**MainRoutes.tsx**

```
const MainRoutes = {
  path: '/',
  element: <MainLayout />,
  children: [
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <Home />
    },
    {
      path: '/users',
      element: <Users />
    },
    {
      path: '/users/:id',
      element: <AddEditUser />
    },
    {
      path: '/roles',
      element: <Roles />
    },
    {
      path: '/roles/:id',
      element: <AddEditRole />
    },
  ]
};

export default MainRoutes;
```

**index.ts**

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withAuthenticationRequired } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const ThemeRoutes = () => {
  return useRoutes([MainRoutes]);
};

// This will protect all your routes at once.
export default withAuthenticationRequired(ThemeRoutes);
```

**App.tsx**

- Using localstorage might not be a good option. I did this for demo purposes. In your case use an interceptor to capture the token.

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Routes from './routes';
import AppRoutes from './routes'; // This is mapped to index.ts

const App = () => {

  // You can use getAccessTokenSilently here instead of getIdTokenClaims
  const { user, getIdTokenClaims, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserMetadata = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const tokenData = await getIdTokenClaims();
      if (tokenData) {
        // use a interceptor in here
        localStorage.setItem("token", tokenData['__raw']);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    const storedAccessToken = localStorage.getItem("token");

    if (!storedAccessToken) {
      getUserMetadata();
    }
  }, [getIdTokenClaims, user]);

  if (isAuthenticated && isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }

  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Routes>
          <AppRoutes />
        </Routes>
      </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: As far as I understand React Router v6 `loader` works with createBrowserRouter and will not work with BrowserRouter

Comment: both BrowserRouter and createBrowserRouter work with React Router v6. Above codes were implemented with v6.4.1

Comment: Generally my question is about how to make React Router loader work in my case. From docs: `This feature only works if using a data router, see Picking a Router`: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader and if I understand right then loader works only with `createBrowserRouter, createMemoryRouter, createHashRouter`

Comment: Look into my `App.tsx` content. get the token in there as I did and attach it to an interceptor. Then all routes will work.

Comment: If you use an interceptor, you won't to call token in every API call. Data will retrieve even a page refresh.

Comment: Im not able to solve this when using RouterProvider and createBrowserRouter with loaders. Loaders will trigger before i have a chance to get the token.. Anyone have an example for a confused developer? :)

Comment: @nios If you follow the step I showed here correctly, you will get the working code. If you can raise a new question with the code that you currently have, I can give you a solution.

Comment: What would this look like for react-router v6 which has the `<RouterProvider>` component instead of using the `<Router>`?